# Is there a way to sort applications on the taskbar in groups?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I use a lot of different applications on my window 10 PC and they are all scattered across my desktop and hidden inside folders. Only a few of them fit on my taskbar and I constantly decide to switch them around or redo my entire taskbar.

I also have an android phone which has folders on it's home screen. something like this (I just googled this picture):

[image]

Is there a way you can have these kinds of app folders on the windows 10 taskbar?

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to your question, but what about opening your apps in different virtual desktops and then you have them divided like that, instead of taskbar folders

Comment: Does it have to be on the taskbar? If not, [Stardock Fences](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/) might do the trick...

Comment: on the taskbar would be the best because my desktop gets messy quickly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add lots of shortcuts to the Windows 10 desktop, there are some ways you can organize them better and cut down on icon clutter. You could shrink your desktop icons, but that might only be a temporary fix. Windows has a few options you can use to organize desktop. Checking the link below about How to Group and Organize Windows 10 desktop icons.
https://www.techjunkie.com/group-desktop-icons-windows/